# Sql Server 2012 listener not working with sql server authentication with asp.net on windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am in the process of setting up an asp.net application on Windows server 2012 and IIS 8.0 connected to a SQL Server 2012 database with AlwaysOn availability groups database. However, I am having an error message popping up when trying to access the application with a login failure message. Now at this point I have replicated the same set up on a Windows server 2008 r2 sp1 and IIS 7.5 and the site works as expected.

My connection string is thus

```
<add name="DatabaseConnectionString" 
     connectionString="Server=tcp:testdblistener;Database=Ibank;User Id=xx;Password=xxxxxxx;MultiSubnetFailover=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

If I replace the `testdblitener` with the machine name of any nodes it works perfectly.

Please help

Comment: Do you have any antivirus installed? Panda, maybe?

Comment: Have you enabled TCP via the Connection Manager?   What is the error message?  What is testdblistener a machine/instance name?